# Testing aspx.cs classes? Should I do it?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mstest

We are using VS2010 with the 4.0 framework with MS test. So my question is should we create unit tests that call the aspx.cs page? We are using EF 4.0 and the aspx.cs pages call down into our repositories ( Classes that create / setup and remove objects from the context ). 
So I know that we need these tests but, should the tests call into the aspx.cs pages or should I separate the calls to the repository into another file that can be tested by is self.  I've never tried to do something like:

```
  MyPage1 pg1 = new MyPage1();
  // Test methods..
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Testing aspx pages is hard and horrible. It sounds as your app is highly coupled if you need to test your views in this manner. Test your repository in isolation, you won't be able to test it in the view but keep the logic simple enough and you should be ok. In other words make your pages simply invoke your repository and return the results.

Alternatively check out adopting a MVC paradigm.

Comment: The above is based on WinForm development. If this is for ASP.NET MVC you've got far too much logic in your views.

Comment: We are using Asp.net pages. The pages are already designed and working, we are switching to use EF4.0. So we don't a lot of time... So I'm looking at the best way to test the interactions with the db. Not sure still if we will be making a layer that contains the calls to the db. And that layer will be the gate keeper to the db.

Comment: In that case you're better off using something like Selenium to get some functional coverage. It won't ensure everything is ok, but it's a start. Having your database code in a view is horrendous though.

Comment: I would agree, but we are making the steps to improve this. All we need is time...